# Is it okay to eat gorgonzola cheese mold?

Tags: food-safety, cheese, mold

My pack of Gorgonzola came with greenish/blue mold. is it okay to eat that mold? I intend to eat the cheese by itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gorgonzola, like any other blue cheese, is *supposed* to have mold. It should have blue mold radiating from "veins" through the middle, like so:

[image: Blue Cheese]

Normally this pre-existing mold actually helps *prevent* other molds from growing, but if you see more than one type of mold (especially a different colour like green or black), then you should throw it out, because it is a soft cheese. If it's just the blue, it's perfectly fine and expected.

Comment: thanks. mine's mold looks more green than blue. like this http://www.foodsubs.com/Photos/gorgonzola.jpg (http://www.foodsubs.com/Cheblue.html), and it tastes sooo good. Its from a big supermarket so I dont expect they will keep bad food on the shelf

Comment: @Midhat: The colour doesn't have to be a perfect deep blue; as long as it's growing out of the veins and not other spots, and you only see one kind, it's perfectly good.