# How do I recognize whether a Gorgonzola has gone bad?

Tags: cheese, mold

Is there any way to know when moldy cheese (in my case, Gorgonzola) is no longer good to eat, without trying it?  Mine is about three weeks old and I really can't tell any difference.

Comment: you can eat your cheese without problem, ripe cheese lasts in the fridge much longer than three weeks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it grows a grey or pink mold around the edges, or a black mold, throw it out. That's an undesirable mold. Those molds aren't usually dangerous, but they can make the cheese taste bad. With gorgonzola cheese specifically, the mold is injected in to the cheese via needle-like things, and then it grows veins from there. If a mold is a different color and it's coming from somewhere other than the veins, that is probably not a good mold. See also [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17631/is-it-okay-to-eat-gorgonzola-cheese-mold).
.

Comment: is this the same for most blue cheeses? also, does grey or pink mold also grow when it goes bad from not being refrigerated for a while?

Answer (score 5):

If the cheese smells strongly of ammonia it's time to chuck it. You will also notice a pink tinge of colour. The cheese from the rind in will be turning peachy pink. Best rule if it smells like cheap perm lotion it's time to throw it away.

Answer (score 3):

Does it still smell tasty? I noted a distinct ammonia smell in a package of crumbled gorgonzola that had been sitting in our fridge a while - it still looked good, but upon trying a small sample, it was inedible, tasting more of industrial cleaner than cheese.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I had Gorgonzola go off it went slimy and wet looking so if it does that or develops a new mould that looks a new colour I'd throw it out.